# Semidirect product of torus with cyclic group: representations/cohomology?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory

Let $p$ be prime and let $T^p$ be the $p$-torus and $\mathbb{Z}/p$ the cyclic group of order $p$ generated by $(12\ldots p)$. Consider the semidirect product $T^p\rtimes\mathbb{Z}/p$ with the natural action.

I would like to know if the representation ring of this semidirect product is known. Alternatively, what is known about the cohomology of the classifying space $H^*(B(T^p\rtimes\mathbb{Z}/p);G)$ for $G$ either $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 3):

For any finite dimensional representation, you can restrict to $T^p$ to get a decomposition into a direct sum of one-dimensional characters, which are given by $p$-tuples of integers.  If a given character is diagonal (i.e., of the form $(n,\ldots,n)$), then it is a one-dimensional representation of $\mathbb{Z}/p$, i.e., characterized by a $p$-th root of unity.  If a character is non-diagonal, then it is contained in the $p$-dimensional representation containing all cyclic permutations of that character, so the cyclic permutation class characterizes the non-diagonal irreducible representations.

Thus, we can describe the finite dimensional representations as finitely supported sheaves on the stack quotient $[\mathbb{Z}^p_{\mathbb{C}}/(\mathbb{Z}/p)]$.  Tensor product is given by lifting to the cover and convolving (i.e., the cyclic symmetry on characters of $T^p$ is preserved).

Comment: Thank you. I was also thinking about restriction to $T^p$, perhaps using induction. I'm looking for a description in terms of generators and relations. Maybe some spectral sequence argument? Bockstein?

Comment: What does the subscript $\mathbb C$ in $\mathbb Z_{\mathbb C}^p$ mean?

Answer (score 0):

As to the cohomology, here is an answer, which is probably an "over-kill".  Probably you can find an answer in much older literature like Borel's.

Since $BT$ has torsion-free homology,
COROLLARY 4.9 of [JOHN ROBERT HUNTON
The complex oriented cohomology of extended powers
Annales de l’institut Fourier, tome 48, no 2 (1998), p. 517-534](http://archive.numdam.org/article/AIF_1998__48_2_517_0.pdf) applies.

With rational coefficients (you can definitely find this in Borel) you get just the invariants of $Q[x_1,\ldots x_p]$ under the action of cyclic groups. When $p=2$, the cyclic group being same as the permutation group, you get the ring of symmetric polynomials $Q[c_1,c_2]$ this way (which happens to be the cohomology of $BU(2)$, and of course, in this case your semi-direct product is the Weyl group of $U(2)$).

Things get a bit more complicated for integer coefficients, but you can read it off from the above corollary.